# Using Python 3 for loop to enumerate through an object and print properties

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.7.2. I have this JSON object like this:

```
cars = {'cars' : [
  {'id': '1', 'language': 'en', 'carDescription': 'this car is nice'},
  {'id': '2', 'language': 'en', 'carDescription': 'this is a blue Ford'},  
  {'id': '3', 'language': 'en', 'carDescription': 'this is a red Chevy'}
  ]}
```

I want to print out the ID and the description of the car, and I do that like this:

```
# print car id and carDescription
for num, sentence in enumerate(cars['cars'], start=0):
  print("Car {} : {}".format(num, cars['cars'][num]['carDescription']))
```

However, with this, the 'num' is always 1 behind the actual id because it starts at 0.

However, if I change **start=1**, it does start the count at 1, but it skips the first row and only prints 2 and 3 and I also get this error at the end:

> IndexError: list index out of range

How can I have it print off the id and the associated cardDescription without getting that error?

BTW I do know that I'm not yet utilizing 'sentence'.

Comment: please always use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions. Use a version specific tag at your discretion

Comment: Note, in Python, this is not a "JSON object". It is a `dict`. *Everything* in Python is an object. To iterate throught the list at the key `"cars"`, you can simply do `for item in cars['cars']: print(item['id'], item['carDescription'])` Use `enumerate` when you want to, well, *enumerate* an iterable. In this case you don't want to do that, you just want to iterate through the list of dicts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use `id` as index itself? With `f`-strings and that it's supported in your version of Python, you could do:

```
for x in cars['cars']:
    print(f"Car {x['id']}: {x['carDescription']}")

# Car 1: this car is nice
# Car 2: this is a blue Ford                                   
# Car 3: this is a red Chevy
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was going through some more recent Python 3 tutorials which indicated that using enumerate was the more modern way of doing loops in Python.  I am not even sure what f-strings are, but I will go look them up. Thanks again.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell, *"modern way of doing loops"*; no not necessarily. If your requirement doesn't need you to access indices, then `enumerate` is not a right choice. `f` string is nothing but a newer version of string formatting; maybe you can call this a *"modern way"*.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell, enumerate is more "modern" than --for i in range(len(sequence)). However, as Austin said, if you don't need the index, then you don't need enumerate or range.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the num for two things: a count and an index.

You'd like the count to start at 1 and the index to start at 0.

Start=1 increases num, but it still counts from the 0th car. In other words, you still end up with three nums (1, 2, and 3). With three cars, num will index the 2nd (index 1) then the 3rd (index 2) then fail with an index error because there is no fourth car at index 3.

Try this

```
for num, sentence in enumerate(cars['cars'], start=0):
  print("Car {} : {}".format(num + 1, cars['cars'][num]['carDescription']))
```

Answer (score 0):

I check if it's dictionary and then i display only the id and car description values.

```
for key,value in enumerate(cars['cars']):
  if isinstance(value,dict):
    for car_key,car_val in value.items():
      if car_key is 'id':
        print("Car ",car_val,end="")
      elif car_key is 'carDescription':
        print(" ",car_val)
```